# Strange date/time protocol, need help solving

Tags: datetime, hex, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer the data sent from a very old temperature/humidity device and decode the date/time and other data from serial communication.

This are some of the older registers of the device:

1997 table
[image: 1997 table]

and this are more recent registers, device is out of date:

2022 table
[image: 2022 table]

At the moment I've discovered a very weird format for the hour:
In the last byte of the registers is where the hour stands in the following manner:
For example, in one of the lasts registers of the 2022 table:
`0000 0000 001D B360 0A10 6343`
0x43 is the hour 13:00:00
In binary: 01000011
If you take the bits 7 and 6 (01) and insert them to the right of the bit 0: 00001101
Which is 13 in decimal.
This, in my opinion, extremely weird format checks for all hours.
This took me a few days, it's amazing.

What I'm asking to anyone who will take the challenge is if you could help me figuring out the rest of the date format.

I really appreciate if you could help.

I tried epoch from year 2000, both endianness, float format, messing around with bits, and xor-ing some bytes in a drowned attempt to figure it out but to no positive results.

Today I discovered the hour and I got really excited!

EDIT: Here is the excel file with the entire device data base: [meter database](https://www.mediafire.com/file/prx6qzod4cjahgu/Enviroment_meter_database.xlsx/file)

Comment: can you provide a few rows of raw data instead of images (text tables are ok)
then point out from that sample which items you have decoded 
**please** don't use images of data, so frustrating

Comment: The last 8 bits (the last byte, the last two hex digits) are the hour of day encoded into aa000bbb for hour bbbaa binary. For example C1 is binary 11000001, so means hour 00111 = 7.  The fourth last byte (0A and 0B in 1997) contains an element of the date, we see that it increases by 1 over midnight every time in both 1997 and 2022. The first two non-zero bytes probably are the weather data, also encoded in a funny way in binary. That’s as close as I can get. If you can provide data from some of the dates in between, it may help, who knows?

Comment: But the days? It very much seems that Monday 6 Jan 1997 ends in 010 binary and 7 Jan in 011. Saturday 10 Dec 2022 ends in 010 too, 11 Dec in 011 and 12 Dec in 100. So it cannot be the day of month nor the day of week. It also isn’t a simple count of days since some epoch date since the difference between 6-1-1997 and 10-12-2022 is 9469 days, so an odd number, but they end in the same bits. I might be able to dream up a weird scheme that would fit those 5 dates, but really we haven’t got enough data to tell. Do we know whether an overflow may have occurred? Since the device is out of date.

Comment: Hello @OleV.V. thank you for your response I will try to add the excel with more data to the first post.

Comment: I managed to decifer most of the data today, ALL data is with a weird way of changing endianness.
For example, in register `0000 0000 001D B360 0A10 6343` , pressure is `0063` and temperature is `BD1` in Kelvin, not ºC.
Still having troubles with date, but it's progress

Comment: I see now that I wrote a piece of nonsense earlier: *So it cannot be the day of month nor the day of week.* Both 6 and 10 end in 010 binary, so it could have been the day of month (your solution shows it was trickier than that, but the day of month was involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I figured it out!!
Turns out that the key was in the endianness, but taking nibbles in account.
In register `0000 0000 001D B360 0A10 6343`
If we think of it in positions like this : `abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx`
So this is:
Temperature : `mlk` , in Kelvin * 10
Pressure : `qpon`, in Bar * 100
Date : `vutsr`, in decimal (date 10/12/2022 is 221210 decimal or `3601A` hexadecimal)
Hour : `wx` , this has a weird arrange of bits: `01234567` to `23456701` this is the hour.

This is the code I made to decifer the register into each value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t registro[12] = {0x18, 0x00, 0x75, 0x10, 0x00, 0x91, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x53, 0x41};
/*
Datos del registro:
Consumo Corregido :     12.9
Consumo sin Corregir :  34.3
Temperatura :           10.9
Presion :               2.64
Fecha :                 26/07/2022
Hora :                  05:00:00
*/

int main()
{
    printf("Registro flashero\r\n");

    //HORA
    uint8_t hora_parte_1 = registro[11] & 0xC0;
    uint8_t hora_parte_2 = registro[11] & 0x3F;
    hora_parte_1 = hora_parte_1 >> 6;
    hora_parte_2 = hora_parte_2 << 2;
    uint8_t hora = hora_parte_1 + hora_parte_2;
    printf("Hora de Registro : %d\r\n", hora);

    //FECHA
    uint32_t fecha_parte_1 = registro[8] & 0x0F;
    uint32_t fecha_parte_2 = registro[9] & 0xF0;
    uint32_t fecha_parte_3 = registro[9] & 0x0F;
    uint32_t fecha_parte_4 = registro[10] & 0xF0;
    uint32_t fecha_parte_5 = registro[10] & 0x0F;
    fecha_parte_3 = fecha_parte_3 << 8;
    fecha_parte_4 = fecha_parte_4 << 8;
    fecha_parte_5 = fecha_parte_5 << 16;
    uint32_t fecha = fecha_parte_1 + fecha_parte_2 + fecha_parte_3 + fecha_parte_4 + fecha_parte_5;
    printf("Fecha en decimal : %d\r\n", fecha);
    uint8_t dia = fecha % 100;
    fecha /= 100;
    uint8_t mes = fecha % 100;
    fecha /= 100;
    uint8_t anio = fecha;
    printf("Fecha de Registro : %02d-%02d-%02d\r\n", dia, mes, anio);

    //PRESION
    uint8_t presion_parte_1 = registro[6] & 0x0F;
    uint8_t presion_parte_2 = registro[7] & 0xF0;
    uint16_t presion_parte_3 = registro[7] & 0x0F;
    presion_parte_3 = presion_parte_3 << 8;
    float presion = (presion_parte_1 + presion_parte_2 + presion_parte_3);
    presion /= 100;
    printf("Presion de Registro : %.2f\r\n", presion);

    //TEMPERATURA
    uint8_t temperatura_parte_1 = registro[5] &0x0F;
    uint8_t temperatura_parte_2 = registro[5] &0xF0;
    uint16_t temperatura_parte_3 = registro[6] &0xF0;
    temperatura_parte_1 = temperatura_parte_1 << 4;
    temperatura_parte_2 = temperatura_parte_2 >> 4;
    temperatura_parte_3 = temperatura_parte_3 << 4;
    float temperatura = (temperatura_parte_1 + temperatura_parte_2 + temperatura_parte_3);
    temperatura /= 10;
    temperatura -= 273.2;
    printf("Temperatura de Registro : %.1f\r\n", temperatura);

    //CONSUMO SIN CORREGIR
    uint8_t no_corregido_parte_1 = registro[0] &0x0F;
    uint8_t no_corregido_parte_2 = registro[0] &0xF0;
    uint16_t no_corregido_parte_3 = registro[1] &0x0F;
    uint16_t no_corregido_parte_4 = registro[1] &0xF0;
    no_corregido_parte_1 = no_corregido_parte_1 << 4;
    no_corregido_parte_2 = no_corregido_parte_2 >> 4;
    no_corregido_parte_3 = no_corregido_parte_3 << 12;
    no_corregido_parte_4 = no_corregido_parte_4 << 4;
    float no_corregido = (no_corregido_parte_1 + no_corregido_parte_2 + no_corregido_parte_3 + no_corregido_parte_4);
    no_corregido /= 10;
    printf("Consumo no corregido : %.2f\r\n", no_corregido);

    //CONSUMO CORREGIDO
    uint8_t corregido_parte_1 = registro[2] &0x0F;
    uint8_t corregido_parte_2 = registro[2] &0xF0;
    uint16_t corregido_parte_3 = registro[3] &0x0F;
    uint16_t corregido_parte_4 = registro[3] &0xF0;
    corregido_parte_1 = corregido_parte_1 << 4;
    corregido_parte_2 = corregido_parte_2 >> 4;
    corregido_parte_3 = corregido_parte_3 << 12;
    corregido_parte_4 = corregido_parte_4 << 4;
    float corregido = (corregido_parte_1 + corregido_parte_2 + corregido_parte_3 + corregido_parte_4);
    corregido /= 10;
    printf("Consumo corregido : %.2f\r\n", corregido);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Registro flashero
Hora de Registro : 5
Fecha en decimal : 220726
Fecha de Registro : 26-07-22
Presion de Registro : 2.64
Temperatura de Registro : 10.9
Consumo no corregido : 12.90
Consumo corregido : 34.30

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.037 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Sorry, I code in spanish.
Thank you for you help everyone!

Comment: Bravo. Impressive. I confirm that the scheme agrees with the 5 dates present in the question. I am a bit satisfied to have my idea of an overflow confirmed, though I had not imagined a classic year 2000 overflow.